# I need a function for the following equality

Tags: lebesgue-measure, integral-inequality

I need an example that there exists a measurable non-negative function $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ which uniform converges to $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_nd\mu$ exists, but
$$\int_X fd\mu \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n d\mu.$$

Comment: Take $f_n = 1/n \cdot \chi_{A_n} $ for suitable $A_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One classical example of what you want is a ["delta-sequence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function). Let $f_n (x)= 2n \cdot \chi_{[-\frac 1 n,\frac 1 n]} (x), \space x \neq 0$ and $f_n(0)=0$. Note that $\int f_n \mathbb d x = 1$, therefore $\lim \limits _n \int f_n \mathbb d x = 1$. On the other hand, $\lim \limits _n f_n = 0$, therefore $\int \lim \limits _n f_n \mathbb d x = 0$.

Comment: How do you have calculated $\int_X f_n dx = 1$?

Comment: The integral of the characteristic function of a set is the measure of that set, in our case $\frac 1 {2n}$. Multiply that by $2n$ and get $1$. Note that the point $0$ does not matter, since we use the Lebesgue measure here and this does not "feel" individual points.